# Discrepancy between draw_quantiles in geom_violin and stat_summary in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile, violin-plot

I am attempting to plot a simple violin plot with the added quantiles (0.25,0.5,0.75).  I use two methods here, `draw_quantiles` within `geom_violin` (straight line) and `stat_summary` (red points).  Is there a reason why the line and points appear to be offset?

Thanks in advance!

```
data <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 
      71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
grp <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(4,6,6,8)))
df <- data.frame(group=grp, dt=data)

ggplot(df,
   aes(x=group,y=dt))+
  geom_violin(width=0.4,draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))+
  stat_summary(fun.y= function(x) quantile(x,0.75), geom="point", size=2, color="red")+
  stat_summary(fun.y= function(x) quantile(x,0.25), geom="point", size=2, color="red")+
  stat_summary(fun.y= function(x) quantile(x,0.5), geom="point", size=2, color="red")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
     axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: A likely explanation is that the quantiles are calculated in different ways, see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2088#issuecomment-291003446

Comment: The `quantile` function has 9 ways of calculating an empirical quantile - not sure whether that would have any impact in your case, but might be worth looking into.